# How to code by contract using RESTful Web Services

Tags: design-by-contract, restful-architecture

Our company as a best practice creates Web Services using a Contract-First approach.

The WSDL is defined before the implementation is considered.

Is it possible to use such an approach using REST? I was thinking of using an XSD however calls are not generally XML! So how do you specify the contract in a machine interpretable way?

Comment: See also the answers to the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469422/should-json-restful-web-services-use-data-contract.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go, will this help you at all?

> At their core, Web services define a mechanism for machine-to-machine interaction using a network and XML. A key component of a Web service is a formal description with Web Services Description Language (WSDL). Until recently there was no formal language to describe REpresentational State Transfer (REST) Web services—now there's WSDL 2.0. This article introduces you to REST and WSDL 2.0, and walks you through creating a WSDL 2.0 description of a REST Web service.

Reference: [Describe REST Web services with WSDL 2.0](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-restwsdl/)