# RESTful Web Services or SOAP

Tags: android, rest, mobile, soap

I am going to develop web services that will be consumed from mobile devices, mobile devices could be Android, iPhone, Blackberry, Windows Phone. So my question is which web services will be suitable in mobility scenario. I think REST will be better but what about other factors? So I just wanted to know which factors should consider when we are developing web services that will be consumed from mobile device?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209905/rest-and-soap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally I'd recommend REST which is the newer and growing API method, but it doesn't fit all needs. For example, if you intend for some existing apps that only work with SOAP to connect to you, you might consider SOAP or even having both APIs.

Some reading I would recommend:

[Compare and contrast REST and SOAP web services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10975863/compare-and-contrast-rest-and-soap-web-services)

http://www.infoq.com/articles/rest-soap-when-to-use-each