# Do I need to Axis to create web service using J2EE?

Tags: java, web-services, axis

I want to create a simple web service to store client request in DB?? and what is Axis used for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Axis is an apache framwework to create SOAP based web services. If you need to create SOAP based web services, axis is one of the good choices. But if you want to write RESTful web services then you can go for frameworks such as jersey, resteasy, restlets etc.

But first understand what kind of web service you need to create i.e SOAP/REST. Here is another SO post to help you find the difference between them:

[Compare and contrast REST and SOAP web services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10975863/compare-and-contrast-rest-and-soap-web-services)