# web services and their usage in practice

Tags: java, android, web-services

There are tons of information about web services on the internet i know. But I couldn't find a simple and clear example or tutorial about how to use web services in practice for Java. I will be appreciated if someone guide me through what do i need to know to develop a webservice
using java and what re webservices usage in practice.

The reason I am asking this is because whenever I look for a job advertisement i come across these Restful, SOAP, JSON, XML web services.. So I wonder about the practical usage of this web services especially if u re not working in a company. For example i will be appreciated if u give an example of how to use web services especially for Android platform..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What web service is? A Web service is a method of communications between two electronic devices over the World Wide Web [source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service).
In IT industry now a days web service developers are on demand,because web service are platform independent you can create a web-service using any technology and this can be consume by using any technologies. Basically web services are on demand when the organization start thinking about the product. For example If a industry wants to develop a product using java technology as a web application. letter on one of the client want to use the same application using front-end as PHP or Android or any other technology. Then organization again need to develop the same application using PHP or any other even though the organization has all the business done already. Here if the product was developed using web services then the organization just need to change the front-end technology his business are already done using web service so just need to consume the web services which will reduce the development time and cost of the product. I hope the above example will help you to understand needs of web services.

Restful and SOAP are the web services where JSON and XML are the message type of web services. you can find lots of differences between Rest and SOAP on the [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10975863/compare-and-contrast-rest-and-soap-web-services) also.

Answer (score 0):

A web service is an API that you give others to access data's that you have. Like how facebook
gives others websites the user friends list, and others sorts of information.

[A ref to the WEB API.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_API)

[restful-web-services-api-using-java-and-html Tutorial](http://www.9lessons.info/2012/09/restful-web-services-api-using-java-and.html)

Comment: These re realy usefull links @TamilSh. Thank you^^

Answer (score 0):

When you expose some kind of functionality to others then you create a webservice. For example, you can create a webservice - it is just a trivial example - which receives 2 integers and returns the sum of them. Here is a small exmaple how you can implement WebService in JAVA.
[WebService JAVA](http://www.java-forums.org/blogs/web-service/1145-how-create-java-web-service.html)

Answer (score 0):

A web service is a way to communicate with a server, basically since most of the apps collect some data on the user (that can also be for a login or something similar) you want to store the data in a place s.t. even if the user will switch a phone all the data of his "profile" will not be lost a practical and good place to start will be something like [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/)

Comment: Thank u sir. The link u suggested can be a good start for me..